# Crazy RatingBar

Tags: android

I'm trying to play around with a RatingBar, but something is really wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/shoppingitem_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my layout XML.  This results in a black view with a white rectangle (that is not small, I might add).  What is going on?

Here is a screenshot:

[screenshot](http://i38.tinypic.com/2liio12.png)

Comment: From my experience, the preview window is not very reliable, does it look like that on the device / emulator?

Comment: Ah, it looks right in the emulator.  However, there are 20 stars and not just 5 like I specified.

Comment: If I set a number higher than 20, it will grow, but if I set a number below 20, it will still show 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just how the layout editor show them.  It's busted.  Can you show the code where you initialize the ratingbar?

Comment: I don't have any Java code.  At this point I just have the RatingBar tag in XML to show it on the screen.  It looks fine in the emulator, but there are 20 stars even though I've specified 5.

Comment: I suspect the number of stars is in the small style's file and is overriding my specification of 5?  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` of `LinearLayout` to `"wrap_content"`.